# Tabular prefix added to all rows including header

Tags: tables

The following minimal working example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
    >{\em}l
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1]
    >{{{(}}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-pre={[}] 
    @{,\,}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-post={]}]
    <{{{)}}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
}

\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{dB re. 40/s conv.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
{} & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
{{}}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean (95\% CI)}&{$<\pm 2.5dB$}&{$<\pm 5dB$} \\
\midrule
oranges  &          0.410188 & -1.791145 &  2.505052 &     0.967500 &   0.999875 \\
bananas   &          0.006144 & -2.185644 &  2.184911 &     0.973375 &   0.999875 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: screenshot of PDF output]

How do I prevent the `>`, `@` and `<` operators from adding to certain rows (e.g., the header)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you mean with *adding to certain rows*?

Comment: Enclose the cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{<lcr>}{Cell content}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{<lcr>}{Cell content}`. As you will see from your MWE, I added `@{}` to the first column to remove the side bearing. The multicolumn command in col 1 row 4 overrides both the `@{}`-command and the `\itshape`-command (`\em` is for LaTex 2.09).

If you are asking how to get rid of `( , )` in the second row, the answer is the same: Use `multicolumn` that spans the affected columns. See (updated) MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}
    >{\itshape}l
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1]
    >{{{(}}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-pre={[}] 
    @{,\,}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format= -1.1,table-space-text-post={]}]
    <{{{)}}}
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
    S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.2] 
}

\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{dB re. 40/s conv.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
{} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{}& \multicolumn{1}{l}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
{{}}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean (95\% CI)}&{$<\pm 2.5dB$}&{$<\pm 5dB$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{oranges}  &          0.410188 & -1.791145 &  2.505052 &     0.967500 &   0.999875 \\
bananas   &          0.006144 & -2.185644 &  2.184911 &     0.973375 &   0.999875 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is your problem, but I guessing, that you looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{input-symbols=<,
             round-mode=places, 
             round-precision=1, 
             per-mode=symbol
             }
\begin{tabular}{
    >{\itshape}l
    S[table-format=1.1]
    >{(}
    S[input-open-uncertainty = ,table-format=-1.1,table-space-text-pre={(},]
    @{\,,\,}
    S[input-close-uncertainty= ,table-format= 1.1,table-space-text-post=)]
    <{)}
    S[round-precision=2, table-format=1.2]
    S[round-precision=2, table-format=1.2]
            }
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{dB re. \SI{40}{\per\second} conv.} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-6}
        &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability} \\
    \cmidrule(l){5-6}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean (\SI{95}{\%} CI)} 
                                            & {\SI{<\pm 2.5}{dB}}
                                                        & {\SI{<\pm 5}{dB}} \\
\midrule
oranges & 0.410188 & -1.791145 &  2.505052  &  0.967500 &   0.999875 \\
bananas & 0.006144 & -2.185644 &  2.184911  &  0.973375 &   0.999875 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I exploit `siunitx` packages also at writing units.